# Reference Coordinates System bounds

Tags: google-maps, coordinate-system, extents

I have a catalog that contains different coordinates system definitions. 
I have a web interface where one should be able to see a given coordinate system extent in a google maps view.

**My question is:**

Given a CRS well known text, for example:

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_CORS96_StatePlane_Missouri_East_FIPS_2401",GEOGCS["GCS_NAD_1983_CORS96",DATUM["D_NAD_1983_CORS96",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",250000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-90.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999333333333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",35.83333333333334],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["ESRI",103397]]
```

How do I find out this CRS bounds in Lat long for example?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do, but a CRS doesn't really have 'bounds' like that. They have origins, and extents that they were designed to cover with minimal distortion (of one type or another). Your example of a State Plane projection *does* have an extent it should be *used* for, but coordinates can be given and plotted that fall well outside that extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EPSG manages all available CRS definitions, and also offers polygons of the areas of use.

You need to register at http://www.epsg.org/DownloadDataset (for free) to download it. I'm not sure if your intended use matches their terms of license.

You have to match the area codes of the shapefiles with the code given in the projection definition database.

The map displayed at [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31467/) shows the same bounds as simple rectangles.